# how to clone a viewRef from one viewContainerRef to antoher viewContainerRef?

Tags: angular

How to clone a viewRef from one component from another.
I can able to move viewRef but i want to clone them.

Need help to build next version of `@ngu/carousel`

https://github.com/sheikalthaf/ngu-carousel/blob/49c402ab917b73a08a10cd6aca4f997666ac2393/projects/carousel/src/lib/carousel.m.ts#L238

In this function instead of cloning I'm creating the item. to avoid this, i want to clone items from `this._nodeOutlet.viewContainer`

```
rightViewContainer.insert(this._nodeOutlet.viewContainer.get(i));
```

if I do like this it moves the view to rightViewContainer. But i want to clone

Any angular experts help me please

Comment: I don't understand the question. You want to clone a viewRef but have it reference a different component?

Comment: I'm creating some embededview in a container and want to clone some of the embededVIews to another container